# Writing BLOB into XML file

Tags: oracle11g, java-6, saxparseexception

I am using `Oracle 11g` database and `jdk1.6.0_45`
I am attempting to fetch an `xml` file in the form of a `blob` from the database and using `DOM parser`. I'm trying to parse the `blob` object and write the output content in the console. Here is my code snippet-

```
String outputFile = "C:\\DEVELOPMENT_PROJECTS\\result1.xml";
String myDocId = "12345";

java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM my_document WHERE my_doc_id = '" + myDocID + "'"); // connection is of type java.sql.Connection

java.sql.ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); // always returns only one row.

rs.next();

java.sql.Blob blobObj = rs.getBlob("DOC_BLOB");

java.io.InputStream is = blobObj.getBinaryStream();

java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

while (((byte) is.read()) != -1) {
    fos.write((byte) is.read());
} // tried writing in output xml file too. this writes junk data into the output file

outputFromInputStream(is);
```

And here is the Exception with stacktrace-

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@19a32e0
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:246)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:124)
    at com.dummy.project.lang.DataTest.newDocumentFromInputStream(DataTest.java:197)
    at com.dummy.project.lang.DataTest.main(DataTest.java:75)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

I've checked the validity of the XML file. After the first line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>` there is a valid `<tag>`

However, I'm successfully able to read an `xml` file from a physical location like `C:\` drive and write it to the output xml. This is how I'm doing it (keeping in mind that fetching the `InputStream` data and remaining steps after that are common) -

```
java.io.File file = new File("C:\\myLocalXMLFile.xml");

InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
outputFromInputStream(is);
```

Here is the common method used-

```
private void outputFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse(in); // Exception is thrown here

java.io.StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(xmldom);

javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(sw);

javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

javax.xml.transform.Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "10");
transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
System.out.println(sw.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the following code snippet worked-

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: But I'm still very curious to understand **why my previous approach didn't work when I was reading the data from the database, but worked just fine when I directly read it from a physical location like C:\ drive**.